# How to access function with its name as string?

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

```
class Dog:

    # Class Attribute
    species = 'mammal'

    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    # instance method
    def description(self):
        return "{} is {} years old".format(self.name, self.age)

    # instance method
    def speak(self, sound):
        return "{} says {}".format(self.name, sound)


args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(getattr(globals()['Dog'](), 'description'))'''
```

The code from above gives the following error message:

```
args, varargs, keywords, defaults = 
inspect.getargspec(getattr(globals()['Dog'](), 'description'))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

But, If I do..

```
args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(getattr(Dog, 'description'))
```

..I don't get any errors.

As I want to access the class names and the function names of one file from another, I just have the string of names, this is why I was trying the previous method which is giving me an error.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Could you please reformat your question, it's hard to understand what are your trying to accomplish here? What do you mean by `I just have the string of names`?

Comment: I mean, I have the names of classes and functions of a file in a list, when I try to call the function directly by extracting the names from this list, It is not possible as it is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to instantiate a `Dog`, but without the `name` and `age` parameters:

```
args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(getattr(globals()['Dog'](), 'description'))
                                                                                ^ here
```

In your last snippet of code you don't instantiate `Dog`.

Perhaps you meant to leave out the parentheses:

```
args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(getattr(globals()['Dog'], 'description'))
```

**Update:**

Also note that since Python3.0 `getargspec()` is deprecated.

The suggestion is to use `signature()` or `getfullargspec()` which each return different types.

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost on the right track. However, you are not initializing the `Dog` class correctly. For the `description` method to work, you have to initialize the class with two parameters `Dog('scooby', 10)` where `scooby` is *dogname* and *10* is *dogage*.

```py
import inspect

class Dog:

    # Class Attribute
    species = "mammal"

    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    # instance method
    def description(self):
        return "{} is {} years old".format(self.name, self.age)

    # instance method
    def speak(self, sound):
        return "{} says {}".format(self.name, sound)
```

Let's run the `description` method as string:

```py
getattr(globals()["Dog"]("scooby", 10), "description")()
```

This shows:

```py
>> 'scooby is 10 years old'
```

Let's run the `speak` method as string. Notice how `speak` method takes in an extra parameter:

```py
getattr(globals()["Dog"]("scooby", 10), "speak")("woof")
```

This shows:

```py
>> 'scooby says woof'
```